# Understanding this basic lemma proof in Ireland & Rosen

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

> **Lemma 2.**  Let $R$ be a *PID* and $p$ a prime element and $a \neq 0$ any element.  Then there is an integer $n$ such that $p^n \ | \ a$ but $p^{n+1}$ doesn't divide $a$.
>
> *Proof*.  If the lemma were false, then for each integer $m \gt 0$ there would be an element $b_m$ such that $a = p^mb_m$.  **Then $pb_{m+1} = b_{m}$** so that $(b_1) \subset (b_2) \subset \dots$ ...

I need help on the part "Then $pb_{m+1} = b_m$".  What do they mean?

Comment: $p^{m+1}b_{m+1} = a = p^mb_m$.

Comment: where did $b_{m+1}$ come from.  I thought the next step would be $p^{m+1} | a$.  Okay, so there exists $b_{m+1}$ st $a = p^{m+1}b_{m+1}$, but how do you show that $pb_{m+1} = b_m$ ?

Comment: Divide both sides by $p^m$.

Comment: Or maybe a more safe wording would be *cancel* $p^m$ from both sides :) You should also consider making your comment into a hint-answer, @njguliyev !

Comment: Maybe to make it more clear, you have $a=p^mb_m=p^{m+1}b_{m+1}$.  Now cancel out $p^m$.

Comment: How can you cancel out, this isn't a mult. group. ?

Comment: Oh, okay, we're in an integral domain.  Makes sense now

Comment: @rschwieb, sorry, you are right. I am not a native English speaker and thus sometimes I write such slightly incorrect expressions. :-) But I am not going to write this as an answer.

Comment: @EnjoysMath If njguliyev isn't going to write his/her answer, I'd like to invite you to self-answer with your solution.

Comment: @njguliyev The wording was just fine, my little bit was just a minor techncality that's hardly worth mentioning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both $a = p^nb_n$ and $a = p^{n+1}b_{n+1}$, then $p^nb_n = p^{n+1}b_{n+1}$. The "D" in "PID" is for 'domain,' meaning there are no zero divisors, and thus cancellation holds. So we get that $b_n = pb_{n+1}$ after cancelling $p^n$.

This leads to an infinite ascending chain $(b_i) \subset (b_{i+1}) \subset \ldots$, which cannot happen since PIDs are Noetherian.